# How can I store output in bash variable and suppress output to stderr and stdout?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, stdout, stderr

If i'm doing

```
oidvalue=$(snmpget -v 2c -c public localhost 1234)
```

This will store the output of that command in oidvalue, however as it is now, it will print some error to the screen. How can I suppress stderr and stdout at the same time store in the variable?

Thanks

2nd EDIT: the below works for my condition:

```
oidvalue=$(snmpget -v 2c -c public  localhost 1234) > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Your edit shows a command substitution that captures only the standard error stream of the command and discards the standard output stream completely.

Comment: For future reference, "_it will print some error_" is not nearly as useful as something like "_it will print the error `Error: you didn't specify -f so I can't furble`._" Remember that we can't see what you can see, so telling us everything is important. In your specific case, if you told us the error message we might be able to advise you how to avoid triggering it in the first place, rather than having to discard it.

Comment: You must use `2> /dev/null` and not `> /dev/null 2>&1` as described (confusingly) on the linked thread... and it must be inside the parentheses at the end.

Answer (score 3):

If that command has no silent option, redirect error to /dev/null.

```
oidvalue=$(snmpget -v 2c -c public localhost 1234 2>/dev/null)
```

Comment: Thank you, but turns out what I needed was actually something like this,
    $(snmpget -v 2c -c public localhost 1234 2>&1 >/dev/null)

Comment: are you sure? this will set oidvalue to error message, stdout will be sucked by  /dev/null . 2>&1 has no effect.

Comment: @dedowsdi is correct... be careful using the `&` you could disappear all output... using exactly his code `2> /dev/null` inside the parentheses worked for me. There's a lot of similar snippets floating around, but they all mean something different.